# Inserting rows to Google Sheets using PHP Google Spreadsheet Client library - "String could not be parsed as XML" error

Tags: php, xml, google-sheets-api

I have a web application that uses PHP and the [Google Spreadsheet Client library](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client) to add rows to spreadsheets.  We use an older version of the PHP library, 2.3.  All has been going fine for months, but as of Friday, August 5th, 2016 around 1:00 PM, we started getting a "String could not be parsed as XML" error for every row we try to add.

Here's part of a stack trace:

0 ... /lib/google-api-spreadsheet/src/Google/Spreadsheet/ListFeed.php(44): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('

1 ... /lib/google-api-spreadsheet/src/Google/Spreadsheet/Worksheet.php(135): Google\Spreadsheet\ListFeed->__construct('

2 ... : Google\Spreadsheet\Worksheet->getListFeed()

It looks like it's not even able to get the list feed.  Did something change at Google on Friday afternoon to make all of our attempts to connect to a sheet and add a row fail?  Has this been happening to anyone else?  How do I fix it?

Comment: I'm using the same library but i cant seem to add rows at all... setting headers like `$cellFeed = $listFeedSheet->getCellFeed();
            $cellFeed->editCell(1, 1, "name");` but that also returns BadRequestException in DefaultServiceRequest.php line 359: Your help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the sheet or the PHP library I am using had reached some kind of limit and once I started with a clean sheet, I was able to insert rows again.
- Doug